# Start homestead serve automatically

Tags: laravel, homestead

I notice that starting the vm

```
homestead up
```

sshing to the vm

```
homestead ssh
```

and then starting the server

```
serve my.app /home/vagrant/Develop/myapp
```

is quite cumbersome to be doing every time you do some work. Is there a recommended way to get your site started at the point of starting the vm? I know I can add it to init.d, but is there anything built in that would do it when adding a new site to Homestead.yaml? Or is this a good feature request or idea for contributing to the project?

Comment: homestead up should be all that is required. You edit your homestead.yaml and the sites property allows you to easily map a "domain" to a folder on your Homestead environment. There should already be an example already in that file.